# How to use SFINAE with a child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have a non-template parent interface and am trying to use SFINAE on a child class. All I want to do is verify the type of the first template parameter can be constructed without any arguments. My issue is in forward declaration. Based on my understanding, SFINAE requires a class to be forward declared and *then* specialized. This is currently what I'm trying:

```cpp
class ParentInterface
{};

template<class, class = void>
class Child : public ParentInterface; // <-- This semi-colon is the error

template<class Ty>
class Child<Ty, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Ty>>>
    : public ParentInterface
{};
```

The answers I was able to find related to this had to do with inheriting *from* a SFINAE class. What do I need to do to get my intended functionality?

Comment: Are you simply looking for "`template<class, class = void> class Child;`", and nothing more?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: The base class is part of the class definition. Leave it out when forward-declaring `Child`.

Comment: Well, your question is somewhat unclear. If all you're looking for is a proper syntax to forward-declare the template, then this would be it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, it is a syntax question.

Comment: So, what's the answer to the question that I asked?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The answer you first gave was what I was looking for. I just didn't realize it was the answer because it was worded as a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<class, class = void>
class Child : public ParentInterface;`

is neither a declaration nor definition.

You probably want declaration:

```
`template<class, class = void>
class Child;
```

And then you can add your partial specialization definition:

```
template<class Ty>
class Child<Ty, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Ty>>>
    : public ParentInterface
{};
```